# Tracking AWS Objects / Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, inventory-management

I have inherited an AWS environment which comprises of over 10 accounts comprising of a whole load of services being used, EC2, ECS, Route53, API Gateway are some examples.  Approx $8k per month for all accounts for example of how much is in there.

So far I have used the billing dashboard to give me some information of what is being used but it's just a point in time, I don't know for example if more services were added today.

What I am looking for is something which will track all of the services we are using and whether it changes, so ideally needs to be something that is scheduled.

I have trawled the web but can't seem to find anything which does this which I know must be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Config is designed to help with this issue.  You can now run Config in your master account, and have it monitor linked or organizaton accounts.

In addition to setting up budgets, you should also have CloudTrail turned on and centralized - this can help identify when new infrastructure is being created.

Because these types of multi-account structures are common and can be complex, there are some very good 3rd party tools that can help as well.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this.  I can see that there are compliance rules so may help with any configuration drift.  I can't seem to figure out after a quick 5 min look how I can track which of the 100+ AWS resources on offer we are currently using.  Should this help me with that as well?

Comment: To track everything you're using, look at your bills.

Answer (score 0):

Have you look into AWS Systems Manager ? I am not sure if this 100% suits your requirement, but to some extent, you can group your aws resources and have insight about them. First you need to tag your resources in order to group them under a single Resource Group.

Built-In Insights includes Config, Cloud Trail, Trusted Advisor and Personal Health Dashboard.

Log into your AWS account and search for service **Systems Manager** which will be under Management Tools.

Comment: Thanks, I have looked at this a few times.  No tags have been set up so thats a task in itself right?  I don't know which services we are using (I can guess at most) so would need to manually go through all of these for each account?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, you have to manually go through the resources and tag them as required in order to apply this.

Answer (score 0):

There are also several third party discovery systems that will map your AWS account. I'm reticent to share specific names as I feel that would violate the nature of SO.

Comment: Thanks, I have looked at a few of these, most of which seem to want an IAM user whereas we are not using AWS IAM we are using AD Integration.  Using IAM breaks the mould a little.

Comment: IAM can be used in conjunction with AD. I'm curious how one would operate in AWS land without IAM.

Answer (score 0):

Axibase has a tool which tracks AWS services using Amazon Simple Notification Service and ATSD. The [tutorial](https://axibase.com/use-cases/integrations/aws/cloud-watch-alert/) is straightforward and setup takes about 10 minutes. The result is notifications sent to you or whomever else via email or messaging service, such as Telegram or Slack, upon service status change.

Disclaimer: I work for Axibase.